# How can I better combine this 2 values that consume the same Publish Subjects

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive-cocoa

I am learning `RxSwift`.

I have setup a view model that responds to bindings in my `ViewController`.

`isValid` checks both a username and password exist and then enables my login button.

`didTapLoginSubject` fires on login press, using the latest value from `credentialsObservable` will call a service.

This all works as I'd like, however I feel something is not quite optimised around how `isValid` and `credentialsObservable` work.

I see repeated code and sense this can be better written, but I am not sure how yet.

I thought perhaps something like this:

```swift
    private(set) lazy var isValid: Observable<Bool> = {
        return Observable.withLatestFrom(self.credentialsObservable).map { $0.count > 0 && $1.count > 0 }
    }()
```

But this obviously did not work.

```swift
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class LoginViewModel: NSObject {
    private(set) lazy var username = PublishSubject<String>()
    private(set) lazy var password = PublishSubject<String>()
    private(set) lazy var didTapLoginSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()

    private(set) lazy var isValid: Observable<Bool> = {
        return Observable.combineLatest(self.username, self.password, resultSelector: { $0.count > 0 && $1.count > 0 })
    }()

    private var credentialsObservable: Observable<(String, String)> {
        return Observable.combineLatest(self.username, self.password, resultSelector: { ($0, $1) })
    }

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override init() {
        super.init()

        didTapLoginSubject
            .withLatestFrom(credentialsObservable)
            .subscribe(
                onNext: login,
                onError: onError
        ).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    private func login(_ username: String, _ password: String) {
        print(username, password)
    }

    private func onError(_ error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view will get new credentials only when something is changed (because `PublishSubjects` work this way). So, it might be useful to store your credentials in `BehaviorSubject` and get the latest state when view subscribes to the view model. It is necessary if you provide some profiled state for username/password.

```
private lazy var credentials = BehaviorSubject<(String, String)?>(value: nil)
```

And prepare the binding in init:

```
Observable
    .combineLatest(username, password){ ($0, $1) }
    .bind(to: credentials)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

You can also use your stored credentials for `isValid` check and for `didTapLoginSubject`:

```
var isValid: Observable<Bool> {
    return credentials
        .asObservable()
        .map({ (credentials) -> Bool in
            guard let credentials = credentials else {
                return false
            }
            return credentials.0.count > 0 && credentials.1.count > 0
        })
        .distinctUntilChanged()
}

didTapLoginSubject
    .withLatestFrom(credentials)
    .filterNil()
    .subscribe(
        onNext: login,
        onError: onError
    ).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```